# Управление

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Янки - в русский язык слово заимствовано из английского языка в середине XIX в.*
Заимствовано в язык - это грамотно? Глагол **заимствовать** ведь не управляет винителным падежом с предлогом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правильно говорите, что глагол **заимствовать** не управляет винительным падежом с прелогом. Можно заимствовать ЧТО и ОТКУДА. А вот заимствовать КУДА - такого управления в словарях не отмечено. В вашем примере наблюдается аналогия с глаголами движения, но отсутствует семантика активности (причастие-то страдательное). А нельзя ли перестроить предложение таким образом: "Слово *янки* в русский язык пришло из английского языка в середине XIX в."?

Comment: Спасибо. Предложение с ГРАМОТА.РУ. Вот я и засомневалась.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, конечно, заимствовано (чем?) и (откуда?). Русским языком из английского.
Но в то же время довольно странно признавать право на существование конструкции "заимствовать откуда" и отказывать в этом варианту "заимствовать куда".
Так что грамматической ошибки в "грамотной"  фразе я не вижу. Вот стилистическая, похоже, есть.